# Javascript getting dates wrong dates when do .setDate(currentDate.getDate() - 30) in some cases

Tags: javascript

```
var fromDate = new Date();
var toDate = new Date();
fromDate.setDate(fromDate.getDate() - 1);
toDate.setDate(fromDate.getDate() - 30);
```

Now when i print formDate this is being printed
Date 2018-07-31T05:33:46.399Z

Now when toDate is printed this is printed
Date 2018-08-01T05:33:46.399Z

The current date is Date 2018-08-01T06:00:46.921Z

so i want to get yesturday's date and 30 days before yesturday date
How do i get previous dates without using moment

Comment: What’s the desired result?

Comment: aren't you already getting previous dates?

Comment: what did you expect it to print instead? We can't guess what you were wanting the code to do, you need to tell us.

Comment: current date is 1 augest so when i do -1 fromDate should be 31-07-2018 and - 30 of fromDate should give me 1 july right

Comment: Shouldn’t that be `toDate.setDate(toDate.getDate() - 30);` instead of `toDate.setDate(formDate.getDate() - 30);`? That _would_ give July 2nd (not sure why you expect July _1st_, though). Also, make sure you spell `fromDate` correctly.

Comment: sorry 2 nd july but even formDate.setDate(formDate.getDate() - 30) should be giving july 2nd right

Comment: @AbhinavMudduchetty It _does_.

Comment: Your code seems to be clear. Before asking such question please search for what you are asking

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`setDate()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/setDate) sets the date relatively. The first snippet works as you're setting the date as `0`, which will set the last date of previous month to the date object. Per the docs

> If the dayValue is outside of the range of date values for the month, `setDate()` will update the Date object accordingly. For example, if 0 is provided for `dayValue`, the date will be set to the last day of the previous month.

But in the second snippet, you're setting the date as `1` (31 - 30), which won't set the date relatively, but absolutely, since 1 is a valid date, and is not outside the range. So, you end up setting the date as `1` in `toDate`.

The correct approach for this is to deduct 31 (assuming you want 1st July) from `toDate`, which creates a relative value (1 - 31 == -30), and thus, sets the date correctly.

```js
var formDate = new Date();
var toDate = new Date();
formDate.setDate(formDate.getDate() - 1);
toDate.setDate(toDate.getDate() - 31);

console.log(formDate, toDate);
```

Comment: I got you but what if today's date is 31 july and i want to get - 30 days which would result to 31-30 and gives me a date of day earlier then that right , and if this is the case i want to know what is fool proof method to get currect substraction from current date?

Comment: @AbhinavMudduchetty -- This is the problem with your original solution. You need to find out the exact days in a month to do that. All months don't have 30 days. What if you are playing with February (in/not in leap years).

Comment: ohh okey thanx got the concept

Answer (score -2):

you missed 31, instead  of 30

```js
var formDate = new Date();
    var toDate = new Date();
    formDate.setDate(formDate.getDate() - 1);
    toDate.setDate(toDate.getDate() - 31);
    
    console.log(formDate);
    console.log(toDate);
```

Comment: toDate.setDate(toDate.getDate() - 31); changed